# Where can I go to learn how to make a GPS app with react native?

Tags: react-native, expo, gps

I am making a fitness app with React Native and want to add a GPS feature that will track the distance a person runs. I am not asking how to do this but am wondering if anyone knows of any good tutorials or courses on this topic. I haven't been able to find anything in my searches that is up to date. I am building the app with expo.

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately this is not really on topic for SO due to leading to opinion-based answers. Find a library first and then look for tutorials with that library. You may want to look at react-native-healthkit and react-native-google-fit. They both contain example apps as well.

Comment: I will check them out. Thanks!

Comment: To implement a GPS feature that tracks the distance a person runs in an Expo app, you can use the expo-location and react-native-maps libraries.

Comment: Thanks Hitesh! I will look into that as well. I've looked at the docs briefly but will spend some more time learning how everything works.